# How to use Python .format() appropriately?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, formatting

Given the following:

```
user_ = socket.gethostname()
runtime_ = time.ctime()
game_days = 'season open'
variable = 'speed'
start_time = datetime.time(15, 0)
weekdays = 'all days'
period = ['1/1/2013', '1/1/2020']
```

How can I use `.format()` see [this](https://pyformat.info/). In order to get this output

```
print(tag)

User-WS, Mon Mar 27 07:30:08 2017  US/Central - season open
Variable: speed At: 15:00. all days 1/1/2013:1/1/2020
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Right now I'm doing:

```
tag = user_ + ', ' + runtime_ + '  US/Central - ' + game_days + '\n' + 'Variable: '  + \ 
variable + ' At: ' + str(start_time)[:-3] + '. ' + weekdays + ' ' + period[0] + ':' + period[1] + '\n' + \
'--------------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: What have you tried? In general you can go from concatenation to formatting just by replacing the current `' + name + '` with a placeholder, so you have a single string, then passing all the names to `.format`. Did that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = '{}, {}, US/Central - {}\nVariable: {}, At: {}. {} {}:{}\n--------------------------------------------------------'

tag = s.format(user_, runtime_ game_days, variable, str(start_time)[:-3], weekdays, period[0],period[1])
```

That is a remarkably thorough tutorial you linked, I didn't know some of that. What was it specifically you were struggling with?