# i want to format some data in link , but iam unable to do that in python

Tags: python-3.x, url, stock

```py
link=webbrowser.open("https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/{year}/{month}/cm{date}{month}{year}bhav.csv.zip")
```

The above is the URL and I suppose to add the some data using format function.

Comment: could you please add some code snippet ?

Comment: `"https://www.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/{year}/{month}/cm{date}{month}{year}bhav.csv.zip".format(year=..., month=..., date=...)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Python .format() appropriately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046657/how-to-use-python-format-appropriately)